# Word search algorithm not finding certain words

Tags: python

## Problem

I have built a word search generator, and now I'm building the solver to go along with it, a recursive back-tracker. The generator generates a word search as a list of lists, i.e.:

```
[["C", "A", "T"],
["U", "A", "L"],
["P", "A", "R"]]
```

The problem is sometimes when searching for a word in this grid, certain words will not be found when they exist in the 2d array.

## Code

Code for the solver (I don't think this can really be minimized much, but it is a complete block of code you can run right away):

```
def neighbors(i, j):
    return [(i + i_step, j + j_step) for i_step in (-1, 0, 1) for j_step in (-1, 0, 1)]

#  To prevent ListIndexOutOfRangeError
def elems_within_bounds(ls, smallest, largest):
    return all(smallest <= elem <= largest for elem in ls)

def finder(grid, i, j, word):
    neighbour_rel_coords = neighbors(i, j)
    for coord in neighbour_rel_coords:
        if not elems_within_bounds(coord, 0, len(grid[0]) - 1):
            continue
        if grid[coord[0]][coord[1]] == word[0]:
            return True if len(word) == 1 else finder(grid, coord[0], coord[1], word[1:])
        else:
            continue
    return False

def find_word(grid, word):
    for row_index in range(len(grid)):
        for col_index in range(len(grid[0])):
            if finder(grid, row_index, col_index, word):
                print(f"{word} found.")
                return True

    print(f"{word} not found.")
    return False

wordsearch_grid = [
['E', 'N', 'I', 'G', 'M', 'A', '*'],
['B', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
['*', 'O', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
['*', '*', 'T', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
['*', '*', '*', 'T', '*', '*', '*'],
['*', '*', '*', '*', 'L', '*', '*'],
['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'E', '*']]

words = ["BOTTLE", "ENIGMA"]
for word in words:
    find_word(wordsearch_grid, word)
```

I tried running the little test code at the bottom of the snippet, and get this:

```
BOTTLE not found.
ENIGMA found.
```

"Bottle" does appear in the grid yet is "not found". When this code is run repeatedly with the same grid, "bottle" randomly alternates between not found and found, but enigma is always found.

I've tried debugging using PyCharm, but I'm not sure where or how to start to find the error, and I estimate any main loop could be running 2,000 times, so it isn't feasible.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: I don't see how I can do that without pasting a 15x15 python 2d Array into the code. And the problem is I can't really show how it differs since it differs on a ru-per-run basis. I tried to get this down to a MRE but this _is_ the  bare-bones solver. I've tried rewriting it twice, no luck, I run into this issue.

Comment: Your example could be a smaller grid - emphasis on *minimal* reproducible example. Your example also needs to be *reproducible* meaning we need to know what the input is, and the result shouldn't depend on randomness. If the grid generation code is working fine and it's the solver that fails, then you only need to show us *one* grid. If your algorithm keeps giving you different results for that *same* grid, then something very strange is happening indeed.

Comment: @kaya3 I've reduced it to a 7x7 grid which reproduces the issue with only two words and that's even when using the exact same grid every time. It seems the more "free room" you have in the grid, the less this error occurs .I haven't managed to reproduce the problem when there's only one word in a 15x15 array.

Comment: When I run this code on Python 3.9.2, I get "bottle not found" and "enigma not found" every time. If I capitalize them, I get "BOTTLE not found" and "ENIGMA found" every time. Are you concerned about inconsistency (which I didn't see) or just the fact that it doesn't find "BOTTLE"? By the way, it looks like your strategy (if it worked) would try to follow a word in any direction at any point; you probably want to limit it to continuing in the same direction as the second letter relative to the first (i.e., go any direction for the second letter, but don't change direction after that).

Comment: @Matthias Ahh I uppercase them at the file reading stage, but I adapted my code for this post. Thanks for pointing that out, I'll fix it. About the fact it can turn in any direction: Yeah, I left that out to simplify it a bit. I'll add that check once this has been fixed. Also, I get  "BOTTLE not found" and "ENIGMA found" every time as well, for some reason, once I uppercase them. To answer your question, I'm concerned why it didn't find "bottle"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def neighbors(i, j):
    return [(i + i_step, j + j_step) for i_step in (-1, 0, 1) for j_step in (-1, 0, 1)]
```

The core of your problem is that at each step you search for a match in all of the neighboring cells *and* the current cell and only use that cell as the search for the next letter.  This means if the word has a repeating letter, it can hit on the same cell twice, and not be able to find the next letter two cells away.

On top of that, if you have multiple paths with a correct letter, you will stop on the first path you try, even if the rest of the word doesn't follow from that path.

This fixes both issues:

```
def neighbors(grid, i, j):
    # Look for all of the neighbor cells, but not the inner cell
    for i_step, j_step in ((-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, -1), (0, 1), (1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)):
        # Limit ourselves to the bounds of the grid
        if i + i_step >= 0 and j + j_step >= 0 and i + i_step < len(grid) and j + j_step < len(grid[0]):
            yield i + i_step, j + j_step

def finder(grid, i, j, word):
    for coord in neighbors(grid, i, j):
        if grid[coord[0]][coord[1]] == word[0]:
            # If this is the final letter, or a recursion finds the word, return true
            if len(word) == 1 or finder(grid, coord[0], coord[1], word[1:]):
                return True
            # Otherwise, keep trying
    return False


def find_word(grid, word):
    for row_index in range(len(grid)):
        for col_index in range(len(grid[0])):
            # Only start searching on a cell where the first letter matches
            if grid[row_index][col_index] == word[0]:
                # Since we matched the first letter, start with the remaining letters
                if finder(grid, row_index, col_index, word[1:]):
                    print(f"{word} found.")
                    return True

    print(f"{word} not found.")
    return False
```

```
wordsearch_grid = [
['E', 'N', 'I', 'G', 'M', 'A', '*'],
['B', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'D'],
['*', 'O', '*', '*', 'F', 'O', 'O'],
['*', '*', 'T', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
['*', '*', '*', 'T', '*', '*', '*'],
['*', '*', '*', '*', 'L', '*', '*'],
['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'E', '*']]

words = [
    "BOTTLE", "ENIGMA", "FOOD", "DOOF", "NOPE"]
for word in words:
    find_word(wordsearch_grid, word)
```

Which outputs:

```
BOTTLE found.
ENIGMA found.
FOOD found.
DOOF found.
NOPE not found.
```